# What do actionFgColor and actionBgColor do?

Tags: bixby

In the `capsule-info.bxb` file, there's two keys called `actionFgColor` and `actionBgColor` and I'm unsure what they do. Is this used inside the app if there's interactive elements or actions? Or is it related to the appearance of the capsule in the Bixby Marketplace?

**Example Code**

```
description {
  displayName (Example)
  companyName (Example, Inc.)
  iconUrl (/images/icons/example.png)
  description (Example allows you to see examples of things.)
  websiteUrl (https://www.example.com)
  termsUrl (https://www.example.com/TOS.html)
  privacy-policy-url (https://www.example.com/privacy.html)
  search-keywords{
    keywords (Example)
  }
  dispatch-name (Example)
  dispatch-aliases {
    alias (Example Site)
  }
  actionBgColor (#BF2519) // what does this do?
  actionFgColor (#FFFFFF) // what about this?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: usage of actionFgColor and actionBgColor]

Here's a screenshot of the (actionFgColor) and background (actionBgColor) colors being rendering on a confirmation button. You can use it to add your branding color to your capsule.

Here's some additional information about those keys in the documentation:

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/bixby-studio.2018-Q2-Bixby-Studio-Release-Notes

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/description.actionBgColor

Comment: Are you referring to the "Buy (TEST MODE)" button? Is the actionFgColor white and the actionBgColor light blue?